# Rails order by association of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am looking to do an order on an association of an association
for example

A Library has many books and a book belongs to a category

The query I am trying is `Library.order("books.catergories.name")` but order doesn't seem to like that. Is there an easy solution to this out there for rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query returns an Array with uniq libraries:

```
Library.left_joins(books: :category).order('catergories.name DESC').uniq
```

This query returns an ActiveRecord:Relation with duplicated libraries:

```
Library.left_joins(books: :category).group('libraries.id, catergories.name').order('catergories.name DESC')
```

This query returns an ActiveRecord:Relation with uniq libraries and preloads all related records:

```
Library.includes(books: :category).order('catergories.name DESC')
```